# Front Audio Panel Issue

Tags: sound, panel

I just installed Ubuntu for the first time, the 15.04 version.
I plug my headphones in the front audio panel but there's no audio even though on Windows worked perfectly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at the settings in `pavucontrol` or your sound device setup elsewhere. It may be obvious from there what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Insert your head phones and in Terminal run the command `alsamixer`, and then switch the  volume bar for headphone by pressing `M`.

If the sound appears and everything goes smooth then you can save the result of `alsamixer` by running the command

```
sudo alsactl store
```

This should save alsamixer configurations to `/etc/asound.state` which gets loaded every startup.