# Front panel audio jack is not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones, audio-jack

My PC is dual booted with *Ubuntu 16.04* and *Windows 10*. And it has dual audio port (front and rear) rear audio jack is working well but **my front panel audio jack is not working in *Ubuntu 16.04*** (it's fine in *Windows*).
It was fine in *Ubuntu 14.04*.
I tried `alsamixer` but didn't helped me.

Answer (score 10):

What helped for me was to run `alsamixer` with headphones in. Then moving right to the column marked "Auto-Mute mode" and pressing down to disable it.

Headphones then worked.

I also ran `sudo alsactl store` for good luck.

Seems to have worked.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. `alsactl store` wasn't even necessary.

Comment: @EgorTensin But each time I switch from rear audio speaker to the front audio, I have to use that command and reset again... Same for you?

Comment: @Rick I'm sorry I don't remember how I solved this eventually. It works without any workarounds now, but I honestly don't remember what I did. One thing I did though was I connected a 3.5mm/mic splitter (like this one: https://www.amazon.com/Maeline-Female-Plated-Headphone-Splitter/dp/B00PYZ2BT4?ref_=fsclp_pl_dp_4) to the front panel headphones/mic ports, and connected my headphones via that cable.

Comment: Can confirm that alsactl store wasn't needed.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open your Terminal (ctrl+alt+t)
2. Enter the command `alsamixer -c 1` in terminal
3. Use right arrow button and go to the headphone
   [image: view]
4. Press `m` to unmute it and press up arrow button to increase the sound
   [image: view]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to search this forum? There seem to be several similar issues with front panel and 16.04.

This one shows GUI solution
[Front audio is not working on 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797029/front-audio-is-not-working-on-16-04)

And this one shows terminal solution
[Front Audio Panel Issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631111/front-audio-panel-issue)

Insert your head phones and in Terminal run the command alsamixer, and then switch the volume bar for headphone by pressing M.

If the sound appears and everything goes smooth then you can save the result of alsamixer by running the command

sudo alsactl store

This should save alsamixer configurations to /etc/asound.state which gets loaded every startup.

Comment: i tried it but didn't helped me, any other solutons?

Answer (score 0):

run `pavucontrol` in the terminal and change the output configuration.