# No sound in Headphone from front panel audio port in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, apt, gnome, sound, 18.04

When I was connecting Headphone in the front panel port of CPU I couldn't hear any sound, actually it couldn't detect the headphone. But when I'm connecting it in the back panel port it can detect. And sound box is also working fine from the back panel, but not from front panel. This problem occurs only when I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, but in Windows 10 Pro it works fine from both of the panels (I use Win 10 & Ubuntu 18.04 in dual boot).
My CPU config is 3.5GHz Intel G-4560, H110M PRO VH Plus MSI motherboard, Intel HD 610 GPU.
Is the problem because of drivers? If so then how fix this (or how to install it) ? 
Or any kind of suggestion how to fix it. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. This answer below helped me

[Front panel audio jack is not working in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889730/front-panel-audio-jack-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04)

When you are running Alsamixer, be sure to do these things:

1. Unmute Headphones by pressing M
2. Disable Auto mute
3. Play around with volume levels of "Front", "PCM", etc till you get the sound coming in your headphones (this is what did the trick for me)

Also note that the Headphones volume will continue to show zero in Alsamixer for some reason, but sound will still be there.
If you want a greater degree of control over the mixer, somebody recommended qashctl ..... check it out. For me, Alsamixer did the job, so I didn't bother

Comment: It worked @gg108. But it could have been documented better. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This worked-out for me. Thought it was better to share it elaborately.
In the ‘Terminal’ write `alsamixer`

[image]

In 'AlsaMixer' select Headphone using the side-arrows keys in Keyboard.

[image]

Now press `m` in Keyboard (mouse dose not work here) to Unmute the Headphone. ( When the Headphone is mute you can see in the column it shows `MM`, and after you unmute the Headphone, it will show `OO`)
[image]

Press up-down arrow keys to control sound in your Headphone.
Now to save the configuration run this command:
`sudo alsactl store`
So the next time you open your pc, it will boot-up with that config.

Answer (score 0):

First, open

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

After the last line, add a new line. This line let the laptop to recognize the audio card. My audio card name is CA0132. You can find the name of audio card by: `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec`

```
$ options snd-hda-intel model=CA0132
```

Then reload:

```
$ sudo alsa force-reload
```

Next, enter command:

```
$ alsamixer
```

In the open window: turn on the option "HP/Speaker Auto Detect"

Note: after the above steps, you can also try to reboot your computer. Sometime it does the trick.

Comment: How can I get a list of available options for snd-hda-XXX model=XXX?

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced the same problem that unable to hear any sound if headphone connected even unable to test it out from settings > sounds but able hear properly if headphone not connected using laptop inbuilt speaker.

I referred all available solutions and even after changing it from mm to 00, it was not allowing me to hear sound using headphone.

I was using Lenovo ideapad and checked other options that available and it was showing F6 for sound cards so I tried to press it but didn't show me any available cards.

Then I pressed Function key + F6 and was able to see USB2.0 which was my headphone. So select it and then press m and increase it from 00 by pressing upper arrow key and after that was able to hear sound properly.

I hope it helps.

Thank you.