# Front panel jack problem

Tags: sound

I know this question has been asked many times but still I can't solve it. I have gone through many threads and tried to do what was suggested but I'm a novice user and some things I couldn't understand.
My problem: when I plug my headphones in the front audio jack I can hear no sound at all and the device isn't shown in the audio settings but it works fine when the headphones are plugged in from the rear audio panel.
Thanks.

Comment: When was the last time the front panel worked?

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS alongside Windows 10 and the front panel works fine in Windows but it never worked in Ubuntu.

Comment: Anything from here that works? https://askubuntu.com/questions/889730/front-panel-audio-jack-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: it is funny that I have tried what was written in that thread 3 times with no results but now, as you suggested it, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks hiigaran for his answer. Btw I want to post here  what I did so anyone with this same issue can work his way out. First I opened terminal(ctr+alt+t by default) then I ran the command alsamixer which opened another window. You can move around by using left and right arrow keys and arrange levels by using up and down arrow keys. Also m key is used to mute or unmute.I had a bar with "Headphones" label and it was set to 0 and had "MM" written at the bottom. First I unmuted it with "m" key then set its level to 100. Then there was another bar called Auto-Mute which I disabled by pressing down arrow key. After this I pressed esc and ran "sudo alsactl store" command and everything worked.
p.s. this is a solution from this thread: [Front panel audio jack is not working in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889730/front-panel-audio-jack-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the connection between the front-panel audio and the motherboard is correct and secure. If the connection between the motherboard and the chassis is loosely connected, it won't work or show up.