# Ubuntu doesn't know my front panel sound

Tags: sound, soundcard

Happy Christmas!
I know my question asked a lot. But I didn't find my answer to solve my problem.
today i switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04.1.
I find that my front board doesn't have sound, but I had sound in windows.
can you help me friends?

Comment: Please define "front board", do you mean an audio output port on the body of the computer? Based on your phrasing these answers likely apply - if you've seen them please describe in detail what did or did not work for you : to differentiate your issue from theirs. 1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036394/front-panel-jack-problem?rq=1 2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/889730/front-panel-audio-jack-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: See if any of the answers in [Front panel audio jack is not working in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889730/front-panel-audio-jack-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04) help.  If not, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1448255/edit) your question to include what you've tried and the results.  Also, thanks to [@MartinCoppersmith](https://askubuntu.com/users/1659241/martincoppersmith) for identifying the potential duplicate -- Since Martin is a new user as well, so wasn't able to post this as a comment or flag yet.

Comment: Also, a request for more information from @MartinCoppersmith -- *"Please define "front board", do you mean an audio output port on the body of the computer?"* -- Again, please edit any information into your question.  Thanks!